# Unicode Font Awesome on CSS :after don't load icon

Tags: html, css, unicode, icons, font-awesome

I am having problems when I try to insert Font Awesome icons on my stylesheets. I have read another questions made in Stackoverflow (and search on Internet looking for the solution) but I didn't find any solution. And it seems strange, because I think that everything is correct.

First of all, I have to say that I have try the next codes with the FontAwesome CDN and loading FontAwesome locally.

What I am trying is apply a Twitter icon to a link related with Twitter, the  code is:

```html
    <a rel="twtr" href="#">Twitter</a>
```

And my scss code is that:

```css
a {
    &[rel="twtr"]:after {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        content: "\f099";
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happened. If anyone can explain I will be very grateful.

Regards, *Iván*

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/sza78vb3/

Comment: So I don't understand why it didn't work fine to me. Could it be because I am working on localhost? I am thinking in that, but if it is, I don't understand why.

Comment: localhost not working - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1r9ksuum/;         localhost working - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ok1p12m9/

Comment: use https: for  //maxcdn so the browser starts looking online instead of the local file system.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. So, if I working on localhost I must use http:// for loading CDN styles in general, or is it only for FontAwesome?